# c# windows service enter user credentials at login

Tags: c#, windows, service, authentication

I'd like to make a program that can enter login credentials for authentication purpose at winows login screen.

From what I've read, this can only be done as a windows service, because it can start before an user logs in.

Can this even be done? Any ideas of where to start?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can't, services are isolated in session 0 and cannot interact with the user.  Google "session 0 isolation" to learn more.  Trusting the Windows logon to be a reliable and time-tested source of authentication jumps to mind.

Comment: I know about session 0, but I have a question: for example, how does a fingerprint software works? (before win7 you had to install a special driver that would log you in when swiping your finger); i'm thinking there might be a way to login "somehow"

Comment: Windows supports authentication providers, chunks of code written in C++ that can act as plug-ins to the logon process.  They don't actually authenticate anything, they are merely data providers.  They can't be written in C#.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to look into replacing the socalled [GINA dll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa375457%28VS.85%29.aspx), which most likely is a scary task ;-)

It says, though, that GINA is ignored in Windows Vista. I can't say whether that is the same for Windows 7.

**Edit:**

Fingerprint software, as asked above, worked until Windows XP by replacing the GINA (Graphical Identification and Authentication). [More info.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163803.aspx)

Now the [Credential Provider API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163489.aspx) is used instead. It was most likely replaced due to the Session 0 not being able to show GUI anymore.

Hope this gets you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to auto logon there are features in windows for that.  **They are a security risk so be warned.**

- [Windows XP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315231)
- [Windows Vista](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Turn-on-automatic-logon)

It may be possible to write something for XP to fill out the username and password fields, but this will be nearly (if not totally) impossible on Windows Vista and 7.